# Excel 10 Vlookup with Multiple worksheets

Tags: excel

I am using a vlookup in a master spreadsheet to show the sales for various categories of products for a specific customer (identified by an account number). There are 450 account numbers and about 35 categories. This is what works

```
=VLOOKUP($A50,'IPC Codes'!$A$2:$AX$5778,3,0)
```

Now I have a new worksheet called PLS Changes which lists the same customers and categories.  Except, the PLS Changes category now shows `XX` in red for categories that had `$$` sales last year that do now show any sales in this year.

I would like to have the cell in the master spreadsheet turn red for any category cell that shows `XX` in the PLS Changes worksheet.  This will allow me to quickly see a product category that had sales last year that has none this year.

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like you're well on your way.

Use conditional formatting, and `AND`. Check to see if it's in the 'PLS changes' worksheet and NOT in the 'PLS' worksheet.

So, something like

```
=IF(AND(in-PLS-changes, NOT(in-PLS)), true, false)
```